# How to install relink wireless driver for LG X130 nebook

Tags: wireless, drivers

how to install relink wireless driver for LG X130 netbook in Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible option, while probably not as good as what the person above is suggesting, would be to use ndiswrapper to install the Windows driver. Only use this if the above suggestions don't work. You can download the XP driver from LG's official site at

http://www.lg.com/ae/support/product/support-product-profile.jsp?customerModelCode=X130-G.ASB7E1&initialTab=drivers&targetPage=support-product-profile

and uncompress it to whatever location you prefer. You can install ndiswrapper from the Software Centre. Once installed, you will see a "Windows Wireless Drivers" button under System - Administration. From there, just click install new driver and select the .INF file which you previously got from extraction. If everything went well, your wireless should be up and ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your wireless card is a Ralink rt3090.

To check this, you can run `lshw -c net` in a terminal.

If this is indeed your card, there is a ppa that someone has created for the driver. Unfortunately, it is only supported up to Ubuntu 9.10. However, there is [anecdotal evidence](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1314747) that it works on Ubuntu 10.04.

You can attempt to add the ppa or download the .deb file and double-click it. This is not an ideal way to install it - it is better to install things through the official repositories, but it appears you have no other option.

Before you do any of this, make sure you update all of your packages (System -> Administration -> Update Manager) and check System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers to see if there is an available driver there.

[ppa](https://launchpad.net/~markus-tisoft/+archive/rt3090/)

[direct download (.deb file)](https://launchpad.net/~markus-tisoft/+archive/rt3090/+files/rt3090-dkms_2.3.1.3-0ubuntu0~ppa1_all.deb)